# Is there a way to load entities dynamically? Load entities after connection established

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Is there a way to load entities dynamically? Load entities after connection established.

For ex

```
const connection = createConnection(...)

connection.addSomehowEntity(myEntity)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a way to do this. But I am curious as to why you need it like that. Ideally, `createConnection` establishes a connection between your app and one of the databases (based on your config) in your server. Since, you already know the database, you should be able to give the set of entities that database should have. Would you explain why you need this?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan My app works by loading independent plugins by that I mean it loads code dynamically. So the plugins exports entities and can use connection. I hoped there's a way to load them dynamically to connection. I asked this question in community support. It's impossible. Except reconnecting every time when new entities come up, but that's a bad decision. I'll try to somehow require entity exports from plugins then create connection and after that load plugins. I didn't find any other logical solution to this yet.